# c# unity container constructor injection with run-time value

Tags: c#, unity-container

I am using unity container XML config based constructor injection in my application. I need to pass some run-time values to the constructor. Is there any way to do that without doing it in code since I am using XML configs?

e.g.

```
 public Calculator(DateTime businessDate)
        {
            _businessDate = businessDate;
        }
//Calculator is instantiated using unity container and mapped in config file. 
//How to pass businessDate at run-time?
```

Thanks!!! in advance.

Answer (score 0):

What you mean by `XML configs`? If you are using `app.config` or `web.config` and your `businessDate` is stored in config file then you can use `system.Configuration.ConfigurationManager` class for that purpose.

```
<AppSetting>
<add key="businessDate" value="22/12/1786">
</AppSetting>

DateTime newdt = DateTime.ParseExact(ConfigurationManager.AppSetting["businessDate"], "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
new Calculator(newdt);
```

**EDIT:** per your comment, you can resolve this by registering the type

```
// Register type
DateTime newdt = DateTime.ParseExact(ConfigurationManager.AppSetting["businessDate"], "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

YourContainer.RegisterInstance<DateTime>("newdt", newdt); 


YourContainer.RegisterType<Calculator>(new InjectionConstructor(YourContainer.Resolve<DateTime>("newdt")));
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.. Yeah by xml config I meant app.config only. I can not store it in app settings as businessDate changes at run-time, it's not static.

Comment: Also, as I said I am using unity container to instantiate the Calculator class and not doing new Calculator();

Comment: `new` is an example. In such case you shouldn't store in config file at all. Rather consider storing it in a `static` variable or if you want better persistance then store it in DB.

Comment: my query is not about storing the businessDate, it's an input to the system from user and changes every time. My query is about how to pass businessDate parameter while using unity container constructor injection?

Comment: @Deepak, looks like my interpretation was wrong. See edit in answer if that helps.